# How to serialize model properly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have next models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)

class ProdcutsAccess(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='hidden_products')
```

I want to serialize Product class and have there field 'hidden_users' that looks like:

> hidden_users : [mark, joe, sam ]

i.e. list of usernames

My serailizers looks like:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hidden_users = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='user', read_only=False, source='hidden_products',queryset=User.objects.all())
```

But I'm getting the error

> is not JSON serializable

How can to win it?

Comment: why do you want to serialize it, did you try pickle?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to use workaround with [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
hidden_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_hidden_users(self, product):
    hidden_users = product.hidden_products.values_list('user', flat=True)
    return [user.name for user in hidden_users]

class Meta:
    model = Product
```